# Refreshing cursor after on ClickMethod

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, adapter

I have some issues with next problem...method fillList() is populating a listview with my CustomAdapter...method is called from my MainActivity and it gets passed object from it
i have to refresh my cursor after onClick method to fill list with data with different arguments 
         public class FragmentChosenDiet extends ListFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    Button next, previous;
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int DayOfTheWeek;
    String formattedDate;
    TextView date;
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    SQLController sqlC;
    private ArrayList items;
    private CustomAdapter cAdapter;


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chosen_diet, container, false);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        //get current date
        df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy EEEE");
        formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());


        date = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Datum);
        next = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bNext);
        previous = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bPrevious);
        DayOfTheWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        date.setText(formattedDate + " " + DayOfTheWeek);


        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
```

filling List
second argument in where clause of cursor is dayOfTheWeek from Calendar class of android

```
public void LoadGrid(Object obj) {
        //


DayOfTheWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        sqlC = new SQLController(getActivity());
            sqlC.open();
```

this is my cursor which is getting data from my database,with selected arguments: obj.getID() which i'm getting from mainActivity and DayofTheWeek which is number of the day of the week from calendar as you can see

```
 DayOfTheWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            Cursor c = sqlC.readJelovnikTable(obj.getID(),DayOfTheWeek);
            c.moveToFirst();
            if (!c.isAfterLast()) {
                do {

                    int tableID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(SQLController.colJelPrehID_fk));
                    String col1Table1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLController.colJelvrID_fk));
                    String col2Table1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(SQLController.colJelDorID_fk));


                    items.add(new Items(tableID,col1Table1,col2Table1))

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
            setListAdapter(cAdapter =new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                items));
        }
```

on Click method

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
```

i'm changing date in my onClick method and my problem is i don't know how to refresh cursor with changed Date i.e. DayOfTheWeek..so it can populate
        //list view with new data, i can't call again my LoadGrid() method from here because i can't pass object to it...like i said before i'm getting my object from main activity

```
            case R.id.bNext:
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
                DayOfTheWeek=cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                date.setText(formattedDate + " " + DayOfTheWeek);
                cAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                break;
```

same thing here for decreasing date
    //previous date

```
            case R.id.bPrevious:
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                formattedDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
                date.setText(formattedDate + " " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));

                break;

        }
    }
```

and my cursor from SQLController

```
 public Cursor readTable(int objID,int dayID){
    database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] allColumns=new String[]{colID,col1,col2,col3,col4};
    Cursor c=database.query(Table1,allColumns,col1ID+"=? AND "+col2ID_fk+"=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(objID),String.valueOf(dayID)},null,null,null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: What is Object here?

Comment: I'm using data access object for managing my class,this object is from class which is describing my table from database with setters and getter..this object which i'm getting from main activity represent which data has user clicked in other fragment so i can get ID from table1 and show data from table2 which are connected

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. You can create a class called RunTimeData, where you save the object. Use as follows.

```
public class RunTimeData{
    public static Object name=null;
}
```

While assigning data do use as follows.

```
RuntimeData.name=name;
```

While using the data use as follows.

```
RunTimeData.name=name;
```

In your case call LoadGrid as,

```
LoadGrid(RunTimeData.name)
```

Release the object when you are sure that you are not going to use the value once again somewhere.

```
RunTimeData.name=null;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for your answer...but i'm trying something like notify my method FillGrid(); that date has changed...is there a way to achieve this,thx again (:

Comment: i have solved my problem with sending _id of object thru bundle to my fragment...and then in my onClick method i have called again my LoadGrid method with _id as arguments of LoadGrid(_id)..i have changed my method LoadGrid so now is using only int _id...is this a good aproach ?